# How to C# Linq Query Select Without Include (no relationship select - no load related entity - just table records)

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I'm using linq to sql class file (.dbml) which is generated from database. When I try to fetch data with linq query such as

```
public List<Destination> GetDestinations()
{
    var query = DBContext.Destinations.ToList()
    return query;
}
```

that query returns all associated/related collections in Destination table. I want to get just Destination table rows only (no other related collections). Cause size of collections too much!

Here is the class file

```
public class Destination
{
    public int DestinationID { get; set; }
    public string DestinationName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Road> Roads { get; set; }
}
```

I dont want to load Roads collection as default. I will include later. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you *sure* it's including all of the associated entities?  Normally those are available, but lazy-loaded.  How are you determining that they're being eager-loaded?

Comment: What do you mean `just destination table rows only` ?

Comment: What you want is the default behavior. You have to write extra code to have related data pulled down at the same time (via DataContext.LoadOptions).

Comment: mean that; there is a table which is name destination. query getting this table rows but loaded related entities!